How to create records via FactoryBot with microservice app
I'm new to microservices, always worked with monoliths. I have an application with microservice architecture. The database is located in the part of app in a gem and is accessed through:
GemAppWithDatabase::Relations::SomeTable.method

How can I create some fake data with FactoryBot for my app? I can't just call FactoryBot.create(:something) because there are no boot.rb and some initializers in this part of the app

"Microservice" isn't actually some kind of standarized definition that tellls us anything about what you're working with. And what you're working with sounds more like an engine and not an actually microservice which would be a standalone application which absolutely needs to be able to boot.
